# calculation take time to complete, but i want to make it processing in background and user can visit another page?

Tags: php

I have php page where calculation take time to complete, but i want to make it processing in background and user can visit another page and when the calculation get competed show popup and user click on that link and show that calculation?

please check this screen recorder of issue

https://youtu.be/nqedwjOj-SQ

database is very big

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can use an async function, and a loading. While is loading, you have the user click show a circle loading (or any other symbol), and when the async function finish, loading is false, and the click can be clicked.

Comment: You probably need to hand the processing to a Cron job in the background. And then server sent events to be able to show the popup. (But also you should consider other forms of notification e.g email in case the user leaves your site in the meantime)

Comment: @MRMarkII that doesn't cover the requirement for the user to be able to visit another page while the calculation is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach explained here uses `Javascript` and `PHP` in combination to solve the problem.

**First Step,**
Make an AJAX request from the browser(with Javascript) to the backend PHP calculation logic. You can seperate the calculation script which will not render the HTML to show full web page. It will send a JSON response with message log to the AJAX request.

**Second Step,**
Save the AJAX request state(running|completed) on browser local storage. It is necessary to make the call persistant across multiple page visits.

**Third Step,**
In your PHP calcualation script you have to save the state(running|completed) of the calculation script. It is necessary to track the progress of the calculation.

**Fourth Step,**
If the user is in the same page for the duration of the calculation script to run then the AJAX request can handle the calculation complete notification. Otherwise check if a request has already been made(from local storage data that you have saved in the Second Step). If yes then retrive the data from the data base(that you have saved with PHP on Step Three).

Hope that explains the process.

Comment: It's not clear a) how step 3 actually works - what if user leaves the first page in the middle of the first calculation? How does the server know that or know how to resume? And b) you don't mention the notification requirement or how to do it. I'm not saying your solution is impossible but some significant implementation details are unclear or missing.

Comment: @ADyson I have added more details. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AftabulIslam how can I Save the AJAX request state and open another page?

Comment: @MandeepSingh Use local storeage of the browser https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp